# Android : constant mouse overlay

Tags: android, mouse, overlay

I've seen quiet convincing overlay mouses in many apps from the store (scummvm, photoshop touch, etc) but nobody ever developed such a mouse (distant from the finger) that can be ALWAYS used, over any app.
Does anyone please know an apk that does that ? I really looked around and googled for the info. But couldn't find any :/